The k-th element in array after sorted the subarray
I have an array consist of $n$ elements $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n$ and an integer $k$.
Given $q$ queries. In each query consist of two intergers $l$ and $r$. You must sort the subarray from $l$ to $r$ in non-decreasing order. ($1 \le l < r \le n$).
Find the k-th element in array after performed queries.
Constraints: $1 \le n, q \le 10^5$, $|a_i| \le 10^9$.
As far as I knew don't have any data structure to sort in complexity logN.
I don't have any solution in this problem.
Someone can give me any idea ?

Where does the interest in $\log N$ come from? Think about possible original indices of elements ending up at $k$. Does the order of queries make a difference?

What's the context/motivation behind this question?  Where did you encounter it?  Can you link to the original source, and/or credit the original author?

We discourage "here is a problem statement, I have no clue how to start" questions, as they tend not to be useful to others.  See here for tips on asking questions about exercise problems.

@greybeard Given that the problem is worded like a competitive programming task, my guess is that the $\log n$ comes from the fact that the parameter constraints in the post hint at an $O(n\log n)$ solution.
